# How to do it in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

New to Informatica.
For Ex: This is a Flat file to Flat file load.
I have a expression that has calculated the data to the sample given below:
The some CUST has one entry with N flag and some has two with N and Y.
I need only the 1 and N or 2 and Y occurrence to be on target table, as sated below, pls let me know how to do it in Informatica.

Source
CUST-111|N|1
CUST-222|N|1
CUST-222|Y|2
CUST-333|N|1
CUST-444|N|1
CUST-555|N|1
CUST-555|Y|2
CUST-666|N|1
CUST-666|Y|2

Target:
CUST-111|N|1
CUST-222|Y|2
CUST-333|N|1
CUST-444|N|1
CUST-555|Y|2
CUST-666|Y|2

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate count of customer. Then, if count =1 and flag = N, pass it to target else if count >1, then pass  to target only the record with flag =Y.
Steps below -

1. Sort data by Cust ID (CID)
2. Use Aggregator to calculate count.
   Use `CUST_ID` as group by. Create a new output port
   `out_FLAG_CNT = COUNT(*)`.
3. Use joiner to join step 2 and step1. Join condition is Cust ID.
4. Then use a  filter with below condition-
   `IIF (out_FLAG_CNT>1 AND FLAG='Y',TRUE, IIF( out_FLAG_CNT=1 AND FLAG='N', TRUE, FALSE))`
5. Finally link this data to target.

```
                            |-->Agg( count  by CID)-| 
SQ --> SRT (Sort by CID) -->|---------------------->|JNR (on CID) -->FIL (Cond above) --> Target
```

Pls note, if you have more than 1 N or more than 1 Y data, then above will not work and you need to attach another aggregator in the end.